# Authorization stopped working after using proxy

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, proxy

We are using ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC with React 17.0.2. Also, Windows Authentication is used.

[By reading this documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually), we've added a proxy file to proxy API calls to ASP.NET MVC Core

So our development config file `dev.js` looks like this:

```
// development config
const package = require('../../package.json')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const commonConfig = require('./common')

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
    return merge(commonConfig(argv), {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: [
            'react-hot-loader/patch', // activate HMR for React
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3030', // 
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // bundle the client for hot reloading,
            './index.tsx', // the entry point of our app
        ],
        devServer: {
            port: 3030,
            hot: true, // enable HMR on the server
            historyApiFallback: true, 
            proxy: {
                '/api/*': {
                    target: argv.env.mock ? '' : 'https://localhost:8800',
                    secure: false,
                },
            },
        },
        devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // enable HMR globally
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.appVersion': JSON.stringify(package.version),
                'process.env.isMockMode': JSON.stringify(argv?.env?.mock),
                'process.env.isDevelopment': true,
            }),
        ],
    })
}
```

However, authentication stopped working with this configuration. All API calls return 401 error.

I thought that CORS can solve the issue. However, authentication did not start to work after appying the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... the other code is omitted for the brevity
    services.AddCors();
    // ... the other code is omitted for the brevity
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy => 
                policy.Requirements.Add(new MyPolicyAuthorizationRequirement()));
        });


    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyPolicyAuthorizationRequirementHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, WindowsAuthenticationClaimsTransformation>();
}
```

And `Configure()` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseStaticHttpContext();

    app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod());

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=FooAction}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

If I build React application, then authentication works fine.
Does anybody know what is wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a [really great article](https://www.sensibledev.com/reactjs-webpack-and-asp-net-standard/#fixing-invalid-authentication-headers) about how we can send authorization headers through proxy.

So we need to use `agent` and send `https` headers through agent.

It is necessary to install the `agentkeepalive` npm package:

```
npm install -D agentkeepalive
```

The complete proxy file looks like this:

```
// development config
const package = require('../../package.json')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const commonConfig = require('./common')
const agent = require('agentkeepalive')

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => merge(commonConfig(argv), {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: [
            'react-hot-loader/patch',
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3030',
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            './index.tsx', // the entry point of our app
        ],
        devServer: {
            port: 3030,
            hot: true, // enable HMR on the server
            historyApiFallback: true,
            proxy: {
                '/api/*': {
                    target: argv.env.mock ? '' : 'https://localhost:8800/',
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    agent: new agent.HttpsAgent({
                        maxSockets: 100,
                        keepAlive: true,
                        maxFreeSockets: 10,
                        keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                        timeout: 6000000,
                        freeSocketTimeout: 90000, // free socket keepalive for 90 seconds
                    }),
                    onProxyRes: (proxyRes) => {
                        var key = 'www-authenticate'
                        proxyRes.headers[key] =
                            proxyRes.headers[key] && proxyRes.headers[key].split(',')
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // enable HMR globally
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.appVersion': JSON.stringify(package.version),
                'process.env.isMockMode': JSON.stringify(argv?.env?.mock),
                'process.env.isDevelopment': true,
            }),
        ],
    })
```